# C fork system call implicitly executed

Tags: c, fork, conditional-statements

I am confused with one aspect of C fork function.

If I do this:

```
int pid;

if ( pid = !fork()) {
    //some code
} else {
    printf("%d\n","Waiting for child");
    wait(&pid);
}
return 0;
```

Fork will be executed implicitly somehow, but I can't understand that. As I see,things like this are common idioms in C:

```
int fn;

while ( fn = someFunction()) {
    //doSomething
}
```

Last example is not related to fork, but it has that implicit part ( condition ) which I don't understand.

Thanks.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In C, the result of an assignment is an expression with the value equal to the value held by the variable after the assignment is complete. Any zero value will be taken as "false" in a conditional test, and otherwise the condition will evaluate to "true".

In both of your examples, the result of the assignment is used as a test for a conditional statement. Some C compilers will issue a warning when seeing this construct, because it is a common mistake to accidentally type `=` (assginment) when `==` (equality) was intended. The warning is usually suppressed by telling the compiler that you really intend to use the assignment as the test value with an extra set of parentheses:

```
while ( (fn = someFunction()) ) {
    //doSomething
}
```

Note that your `fork()` works because `wait(0)` will wait for any child process in the same process group as the parent. However, the variable `pid` does not really hold a process identifier. It is holding the result of the logical-not applied to the result of the `fork()` call.

Answer (score 1):

There is no such thing as "implicit". Where you call a function with parenthesis, the function is called. `pid` will have the return value of `fork`, and `fn` will have the return value of `someFunction`. The condition applies, in your case, on these values.

Comment: Actually, since this example says `if ( pid = !fork())`, `pid` will not have the return value of `fork()`. It'll be equal to `0` in the parent, and `1` in the child.